# Вопрос по документации - Реализация остановки ШИМа путем подачи высокого уровня на вход ETRF

Tags: stm32, arm, микроконтроллеры

Пытаюсь понять [Reference manual stm32f103](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/2/26/STM32F1-Reference.pdf) на стр.375, п.15.3.11 "Clearing the OCxREF signal on an external event".

Использую TIM2. Выставил Clock Source = ETR2 для первого канала, второй канал настроил в режиме ШИМ.

Первый канал подключил к порту Ардуинки - она поднимает и опускает напряжение каждые 4 мсек, поделил напряжение до 3,3 Вольта и подключил к первому каналу STM.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю референс мануал, должно быть так - когда Ардуинка подает ток на PA0, STM это видит и приостанавливает ШИМ PA1, пока Ардуинка не перестанет подавать напряжение.

Но получается следующее (на картинке снизу D1 - сигнал, который подает Ардуинка на PA0; D2 - сигнал от PA1):
[image: Сигнал на вход первому порту(D1) и выходной ШИМ второго порта микроконтроллера(D2)]

STM крутит ШИМ и не реагирует. Делал все как написано в документации, выставлял все биты напрямую через CMSIS, и попробовал уже через HAL это реализовать.

Правильно ли я понял этот раздел документации? Можете скинуть практический пример? Находил только пустое описание как в документации.